# Excel Filter - VBA to automate

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I have a requirement which needs me to select only the values that are greater than zero. It has got texts and numbers as well. Here is the sample data,

```
Name    Marks   Remarks
ab      90         Good
bc      0          Bad
cd     70          Average
de      0          Bad
fg    didn'tattend  Poor
```

and I want my output using VBA to be like this,

```
Name    Marks
ab      90
cd      70
```

and the output is on the different sheet as well. Kindly tell me which one is the best for this requirement.

I need a VBA SUB that takes these data and produce the above output. I am trying. But its not getting there.

The code that I tried,

```
Private Sub OpenExcelFile_Click()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = [Control!A1]

Sheets("Section1").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose the required file", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.xls (*.xls),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)
    For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
        With Sheet.UsedRange
            .Copy PasteStart
            Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
        End With
    Next Sheet
End If
    wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one hand it will be difficult that somebody writes the code for you, and on the other hand, which is good new, you can do this easily with the built-in Excel table. Just simply click on one of the cells of your data, go to Insert tab, choose Insert a Table and check mark my table has headers. Then you will see each column has a filtering icon, use the Marks column and go to Number filters and choose Greater than or Equal to 70 to get the result you showed.

Comment: Thanks @Ibo. I got It.